# How to use fontawesome without 'fa-icon' tag

Tags: css, angular, svg, font-awesome, primeng

Fontawesome-angular can be used via the following tag:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fal', 'info-circle']"></fa-icon>
```

In some cases - like the primeng accordion - the default icon can be replaced by setting css classes.
Is there a way to access the fontaweome svg images by providing the names as classes without the fa-icon tag?

Something like this:

```
<i class="fal fa-info-circle"></i>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible.. Update fal to fas in class name.. Check below anwser..

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhou6o) add this to index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in the class name.. Try this..

```
<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
```